# Google maps hide marker title in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to add a Marker into my Google map. Here is the code.

```
private final LatLng LOCATION_HOME= new LatLng(6.0334009,80.218384);


 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LOCATION_HOME)
                    .title("Hi I'm Home..:D")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
    );
```

Using this code, I can get the marker title by touching the marker. How can I hide the marker title by toucing it again?

I tried to find a method. But, goggle say only how to hide the markers. but, I need the marker to stay and hide only the marker title.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this callback to manage the click on the info window.

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```

Or maybe its better for you to implement this method:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
```

Then you can call

```
hideInfoWindow()
```

on the marker to hide it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how it works. Is it hide the marker title by touch?

Comment: hideInfoWindow() hides it, you only need to choose when to hide it, on the info window click or marker click

Answer (score 3):

First create a marker variable

```
Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Then make sure that marker is tapped

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(mMarker))
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        return true;
    }
});
```

You can also implement `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` if the user tap on the info window

Answer (score 0):

Create marker object and call marker.hideInfoWindow(); look this

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
```

marker.hideInfoWindow();

Answer (score 0):

you can easily not give it the title in the first place and voila!!